# How to Filter out array of object using the key

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array like this

```
let a = [{'contract_1': "test 1"},
{'contract_2': "lease 1"}]
```

I want to filter this out and and completely remove the object which has the key "contract_1".

The finale result should be

```
let a = [{'contract_1': "test 1"}];
```

I have already tried to catch the key like this.

```
a.filter(item => {return item['contract_1'] !== 'contract_1'})
```

Comment: Do all the objects just have one property?

Comment: const results = a.filter((data) => !data["contract_1"]); Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @Barmar I have already tried with few options.. But didnt got the exact output i wanted So i thought to get suggestions by adding here. Hope its not wrong. :) 
and yes all the objects will be like this, The problem i had is filter it by the key when the key is changing like this

Comment: @AliKlein Now I understands. Thank you..

Comment: If you got the answer you wanted, you obviously wouldn't be posting here. We still want you to show what you tried. That way we can explain what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated the question. And the way AliKlein posted is working. I Didnt had the idea about how to catch an object when its not having a same same key name (like this {name : "name, something : "something"}. My code will work for this way. but since here the object is like {name : something} Thats why i thought to ask it here. Thanks for mentioning the rules.

Comment: It's generally poor design to have an array of object with different keys in the first place. Why not have a single object with all the keys?

Comment: I also the need the values and this is already made in the old code. But as you say i can update it to the proper key value pair objects. Maybe thats better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hasOwnProperty()` method to test if a key exists in an object.

```js
let a = [{
    'contract_1': "test 1"
  },
  {
    'contract_2': "lease 1"
  }
];

a = a.filter(el => !el.hasOwnProperty('contract_1'));

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you.. I will try this

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = [{
    'contract_1': "test 1"
  },
  {
    'contract_2': "lease 1"
  }
];

a = a.filter(el => {
  const [key] = Object.keys(el);

  return key !== 'contract_2';
});

console.log(a);
```

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Got the idea. Thank you.